# lite weight and SIMPLE jquery auto suggest/autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

all i need is a very simple auto complete that suggests words that have the letters the user is typing in them, very simple, nothing fancy, either inline or from an external file, i only need about 20 or so results to be suggested total.

I saw this one: http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/?

but it's 8kb, which is pretty big for what I need it for, does anyone know of a smaller light weight autocomplete script? or does anyone know the jquery to provide a super simple autocomple?

and i'm not using Jquery UI, that's a crappy bloated add-on to Jquery, so I can't use their autocomplete, i'm sure it's 10000mb large anyways.

Comment: jQuery UI core, widget, and autocomplete (the required components to get autocomplete to work) is 20KB, which still might seem excessive to you, except that if you use the google CDN there's a fair chance that that equals 0KB of download for your users, which I would guess is better than your other options.

Comment: Where do you get the list of words? Is this any word in English with the letters the user is typing, or only certain words? -------- Have you actually tried [ **the jQuery UI autocomlete?** ](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)... it seems quite nice.

Comment: If all you need is auto-complete then UI might be bloated... but no matter how you look at it its far from crappy.

Comment: It's doubtful that google has that specific 19kb on their CDN.  Some or all of it is available CDN, but not the specific one for autocomplete

Comment: not to mention, 19kb is horrific for a simple auto complete, when it can be done in 1kb or 1005b (and it's a badass little 1kb script that I eventually created).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-json-suggestsearch-box/
customize this as per your requirement

Comment: Nice. 2nd version has 7KB size and You could minimize it additionally to 3KB.

Comment: failed link 16.Jul.2013

Comment: downvoting, it's no longer working redirecting to someone's LinkedIN profile instead!

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20120502105942/http://tomcoote.co.uk/javascript/jquery-json-suggestsearch-box-v2/ this link should work

Answer (score 0):

if 19kb is large, the one you mention is deprecated, then write your own.  You can cut out the generalizations he makes that add some bloat.  You would probably do yourself a favor using the one from jQuery UI, since it undergoes rigorous testing.